# Lauching a task when WIFI connects on Android Oreo or newer

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

I have an [app](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=es&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://github.com/daxslab/es_wifi_etecsa&xid=17259,15700023,15700043,15700124,15700186,15700190,15700201,15700237,15700242,15700248&usg=ALkJrhhZfAmFUHzvLlZ01xE5bkYo6f3YCg) that run some security checks and alerts the user using notifications when the device connects to a WIFI network with an specific SSID. The app run checks in background and if there is some security issue alerts the user using notifications.

The issue is that I was using a broadcast receiver for this but with Android Oreo or newer is not working any more. I was reading a lot and I can't find a way for running some background action exactly when the WIFI connection is turned on.

I am missing something or Google has killed my app?

Comment: Use a foreground service with a dynamically-registered receiver.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your suggestion, i think that will be the way to go, but a continuously running foreground service will not drain the device battery?

Comment: A service on its own does not drain battery. It will tie up system RAM, but how much battery is used depends entirely on what the service does.